# How to update the content of a Shell page when you log out or return to the same page Xamarin forms

Tags: shell, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms Shell, I have a Login (ShellItem) that is the first page to appear and when the session starts it shows a home page (FlyoutItem) that shows the data of how many points the user has.

The problem is that when I open the other pages of the hamburger menu and return to it, they are still open where I left off, the same happens when I log out and enter with another user, the pages of the previous session are still open with the same data from the previous user . Now how can I update the content page of the Shell every time you have to navigate to the same page again, to load again with the new data of the new user who starts session.

I tried from xaml.cs with the

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    ShowData();
}
```

but it won't let me call the methods of the viewModel that load the data, because the View is not supposed to know the viewmModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i create new application using flyout (file -> new project), Xamarin give me example code, and I still using it until now, here's the code (or you can try create new project and see it from there):

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemsViewModel _viewModel;

    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = _viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

In the ItemsViewModel:

```
public void OnAppearing()
    {
        //do your code
    }
```